# Kotlin: The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, gradle

I have an app coded in react native that I'm trying to upload to the google play store, but I'm running into some issues when I am trying to compile the .aab file.

Whenever i try to reload my gradle project I am greeted with 356 errors all relating to the version of kotlin used to compile.

(This is the error message:
`e: E: ... \App\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\utils\TaskUtils.kt: (24, 12): Class 'kotlin.collections.ArraysKt___ArraysKt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.`

`The class is loaded from C:/Users/USERNAME/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-8.0-rc-1-bin/di0yrgntpr7ydpxe8yasu72eh/gradle-8.0-rc-1/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0-RC2.jar!/kotlin/collections/ArraysKt___ArraysKt.class`)

I have already changed my build.gradle file to include the current versions of gradle and kotlin, this is what it looks like:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        //kotlin_version = '1.8.0' //use latest

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    //ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.21' //use latest

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0-alpha11")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0-alpha11")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        //implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1、ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'

2、Setting the following in the project build.gradle:

change "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" version to "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0

3、Setting the following in the app build.gradle:

check 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' version

Because attribute "$kotlin_version"  has been updated